# PrimeReact 3.4, DataTable, sort only in controlled mode

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I'm using Primereact 3.4's DataTable component in "controlled" mode: I supply the data, sortField, sortOrder and onSort, just as shown in their example code:

```
<DataTable value={this.state.cars} sortField={this.state.sortField} sortOrder={this.state.sortOrder} onSort={(e) => this.setState({sortField: e.sortField, sortOrder: e.sortOrder})}>
    <Column field="vin" header="Vin" sortable={true}/>
    <Column field="year" header="Year" sortable={true}/>
    <Column field="brand" header="Brand" sortable={true}/>
    <Column field="color" header="Color" sortable={true}/>
</DataTable>
```

I'm also using pagination, since this is a very large block of data; I show 50 records per page.

Everything is working as expected, except that when a user sorts a column, Datatable does a sort as it would in uncontrolled mode -- sorts the 50 rows it has in the DOM -- and then shortly afterward my sort function completes, supplying DataTable with newly-sorted data from my back-end API.

How do I tell DataTable to **only** use my sort function, and not also try to do its own, uncontrolled sort?

Comment: Maybe supply a custom `sortFunction` that doesn't actually sort. (Don't know if `sortFunction` is present in PR 3.4 or not.)